# Can I use the display shelf as an input for a second camera?

Tags: pi-4, camera, display, picamera

I would like to use two different cameras with the raspberry pi 4 and I wondered if I could use the display shelf as the secondary camera input or if I need to acquired the adpater that exists for the purpose.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope. How are you going to push data into a video out port? Just get a USB cam.

Comment: Totally! Thank you @DmitryGrigoryev